# Как сохранить созданные на карте метки, чтобы их могли видеть остальные пользователи?

Tags: javascript, django

Делаю школьный проект на Django с использованием яндекс карты. Возникла проблема, что после перезагрузки страницы, все метки, созданные на карте, стираются. Суть моего сайта в том, что пользователь, путём нажатия на карту мышкой или вводом в специальное поле адреса, создаёт на карте событие(метку), которое могут видеть другие пользователи. Как мне сделать так, чтобы это событие, созданное пользователем, сохранялось на карте и его могли видеть все остальные пользователи сайта?

Comment: Сохранять в базу данных эту метку. При загрузке страницы ее отрисовывать. Не знаком с яндекс картами, может там есть какой функционал

Comment: Это дубликат вопроса